# How to implement Azure AD B2C PasswordReset functionality in an iOS App

Tags: ios, azure-ad-b2c

In a (Swift) iOS app that is using Azure AD B2C authentication, you can call the SignIn_Signup policy that opens a Safari browser where you can Login or Register a new account. I would like this page to also have a Password Reset link.

But when that link is clicked you can’t return to the iOS app, catch the `AADB2C90118` exception and call the PasswordReset policy in the same browser because the Safari browser is sandboxed. (This is the way a windows app handles PasswordReset requests)

How can I call a PasswordReset policy from a link in the `SignIn_Signup` browserscreen in an iOS app?

I’ve looked at the iOS B2C sample with MSAL but it doesn’t have a PasswordReset.

(a workaround would be to call the PasswordReset policy from a second button in the iOS app but I want it to be called from the Safari browser.)

Btw, I am using Custom Policies because I have to do some server side validation.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to call a password reset policy without returning back to your app, but out of curiosity, why does it matter that the browser is sandboxed?

Comment: You are completely right. It doesn't matter at all that it's sandboxed. We changed the iOS app: On clicking the PasswordReset link the app now returns with the AADB2C90118 exception and starts a new browser with the PasswordReset policy. This works OK. The only issue is that the Safari browser is closed completely and is opened again with the Password Reset page. But I don't think you can use the same browser window... or can you?

Comment: Nope you can't - you should vote for that feature though: https://aka.ms/aadb2cfeedback

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to call a password reset policy without returning back to your app. You should vote for that feature though: aka.ms/aadb2cfeedback

Comment: I added this feature. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32282461-go-from-signupsignin-to-passwordreset-without-retu